# Obtaining the most important terms in a certain spherical integral involving Hermite polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, spherical-coordinates, hermite-polynomials

Let $d$ be a large positive integer and $t \in [-1,1]$. For any pair of integers $n,m \ge 0$ of same parity, define $s_{nm}$ by
$$
s_d(n,m)=\frac{d-2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}rdr\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\,  (1-r^2)^{d/2-2}H_n\left(rt\cos\phi+r\sqrt{1-t^2}\sin\phi\right)H_m(r\cos\phi).
$$
where $H_n(z)$ is the probabilist's $n$th Hermite polynomial. Note that $s_{nm}$ is itself a polynomial in $t$ (of degree at most $\min(m,n)$). Finally let $k$ be a positive integer $\le \min(m,n)$.

> **Question.** *As a function of $n$, $m$, $k$, and $d$, what is a good estimate (valid for large $d$) for the coefficient $s_d(n,m)[t^k]$ of $t^k$ in $s_d(n,m)$ ?*

### Solution for $k = 0$ and $k=1$

Via an order-$1$ Taylor expansion of $H_n(rt\cos\phi + r \sqrt{1-t^2}\sin\phi)H_m(r\cos\phi)$ around $r=0$, it was shown in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405901/78539) that for $k=0$, we have
$$
s_d(n,m)[t^0] =
\begin{cases}
 H_n(0)H_m(0)+(1/d)(H_n(0)H_{m+1}(0)+H_{n+1}(0)H_m(0)),&\mbox{ if }n,m\text{ even },\\
0,&\mbox{ else.}
\end{cases}
$$
Likewise, for $k=1$, we have
$$
s_d(n,m)[t^1] =
\begin{cases}(1/d)H_{n+1}(0)H_{m+1}(0),&\mbox{ if }n,m\text{ odd },\\
0,&\mbox{ else.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: "it was shown in this post"... I think you forgot to provide a link!

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Fixed.